# How to get the last child of a specific type in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'd like to know how to get the last child of a specific instance in JavaFX.

There is a simple way I know to get just the last child by subtracting `1` to the size of the list and assume that it returns at least a `0` value:

```
List<Node> children = getChildren();
int index = children.size() - 1;
Node lastChild = (index > -1) ? children.get(index) : null;
```

But I was looking for a specific instance, something like the [:last-of-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp) selector in CSS.

Comment: There's no implementation but it's simple enough to do this `Node lastOfType = null; for (int i = children.size(); i >= 0; i--) { Node child = children.get(i); if (child instanceof Type) {lastOfType = child; break; }}`

Comment: @fabian Oooh, iterate over from last to first! I guess I'm aging now ha ha... Thank you.